# Does my HP laptop have a secret temperature sensor?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling

I have an HP Envy x360 2-in-1 laptop with a 4700U processor. The fan in the laptop is usually not running and it is very quiet, which is great. However, after an hour or so of use the fans speed up and it gets loud at about 3000RPM. I thought to myself that this must occur because the laptop is getting warm and heat sensors are telling the fans to go faster. I therefore installed Speedfan and see three sensors: HD0, Temp1, and Temp2.

Curiously, the fans speed up even if these are all under 35C. The fans go faster seemingly regardless of the temperatures displayed by these sensors. The fans will go slow at 35C and after an hour of 35C the fans go faster.

Does my HP laptop have a secret temperature sensor? What is telling the fans to go faster, if not these three sensors? In addition, is it possible to control the fan speeds? Nothing in the BIOS suggests this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. You may see that some apps say that your processor heat is like 40 degrees Celcius.

That is an inbuilt function of the processor. They cannot help you see the temperature of the outside world.

Regarding the fans, that is inbuilt software that occurs. I have an ASUS, and i can change some gaming settings. Whenever i bring them up, the fans also start running. If they did not run, my processor would slowly heat up.

The reason they may be running is for safety issues so the processor does not heat up and cool down fast so they do not get damaged.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Fans are controlled by a fan controller, fan controllers read data from sensors to dictate fan speed, and sensors read temperatures of components. So, what sensor is dictating the fan speeds?

Comment: By that, i mean there are software controllers. Some laptops are designed like that. I forgot the exact model, but a DELL latitude don't have a sensor, but are software controlled, meaning that the fan will go faster when the CPU or GPU are taken above their average level of usage, such as when you are gaming.

Comment: For example, your CPU has a max temp of 105 Celcius, and a default of 15 Wats. Whenever a demanding program runs, the wattage increases to, let's say as an example, to 23 (max for your CPU is 25 W). Then, software encoded into the laptop sees that it needs to increase the fan speed so that it does not overheat.    This is not a very good thing s the fan can be running for no reason or does not run when it is meant to.

Comment: BUT!!! There can be a sensor on your laptop, and as mentioned before depending on the amount of juice your CPU or GPU takes in, it may speed up the fans. This may be the things that are happening to you. Or, the laptop is predicting the temperature based on the stage and the processor efficiency and other factors.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems silly to run fan speeds based on anything other than tempetature

Comment: @Behacad i have read the schematics of your processor, that being the 4700U and i have found out that it does not have a specific sensor for temperature, but has different components that give estimates that a software calculates. That software then specifies how the Fan runs and how the processor functions. This means that there is a 1-celsius leeway for what the software outputs

Comment: @Behacad i have also looked at my own processors schematic, and i found that my one also has the same way of telling the temperature. My one is an Intel I7. I think a lot of processors follow the same schematic as it is a bit cheaper and is less prone to damage.

Comment: @Behacad, i have remembered that you can test if is software or hardware if you go and get a different operating system. I suggest get a bootable Linux on a USB, boot to your laptop, then see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the info